# Query values from list using Select_analysis() in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select

I have a list like this...

```
list = ['1','2','3','4']
```

how can I use arcpy.Select_analysis to select features that have the attributes in the list.

```
qry = '"SECDIVNO" IN ' + str(tuple(list))           
arcpy.Select_analysis(tempFeat_1, tempFeat_2, qry)
```

Is the "tuple" incorrect?

I've tried this also and it doesn't work either...

```
qry = '"SECDIVNO" IN ' + list           
arcpy.Select_analysis(tempFeat_1, tempFeat_2, qry)
```

The error I get is always the "invalid expression error"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code that should work for you:

```
import arcpy

mylist = ['A4126','A4190']
print str(tuple(mylist))

tempFeat_1 = r"C:\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\AR_postalcodes"
tempFeat_2 = r"C:\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\AR_postalcodes_sel"
qry = """POSTCODE IN {0}""".format(str(tuple(mylist)))

arcpy.Select_analysis(tempFeat_1, tempFeat_2, qry)
```

A couple of comments:

1. Depending on where your source data is stored, it is the best to use [AddFieldDelimiters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000006p000000) because sometimes you need to use [different quotes and brackets](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Specifying_a_query_in_Python/002z0000001r000000/) around field names. The code I published above is for file geodatabase.
2. Never use reserved words as variables (use mylist instead of list).
3. Use [three quotes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SQL_reference_for_query_expressions_used_in_ArcGIS/00s500000033000000/) around strings with complex content.

Comment: You'd be better off using `"POSTCODE IN ({0})".format(", ".join(str(item) for item in mylist))`, depending on Python to do the syntax formatting is a little...scary.